# (centOS) cloud-init not pulling ssh

Tags: openstack, qcow2

Trying to build CentOS 6 qcow2 image with OpenStack guide[http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/centos-image.html].
I'm using "cloud-init" instead of the "/etc/rc.d/rc.local" script but I assume "cloud-init" overrides the script?
I successfully created the image, uploaded and created the instance. But can't ssh into it. I suspect that the instance is not pulling ssh public key from the OpenStack server/controller.

[UPDATE: Trying an alternative method by allowing ssh by password]

These are the logs I get from OpenStack admin page.

```
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +-------+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway  |    Genmask    | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   0   |   10.6.1.0  | 0.0.0.0  | 255.255.255.0 |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   1   |   0.0.0.0   | 10.6.1.1 |    0.0.0.0    |    eth0   |   UG  |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------+
Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:config' at Thu, 05 Nov 2015 23:55:05 +0000. Up 15.43 seconds.
Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:final' at Thu, 05 Nov 2015 23:55:06 +0000. Up 17.00 seconds.
ci-info: ++++++++++Authorized keys from /home/centos/.ssh/authorized_keys for user centos+++++++++++
ci-info: +---------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+
ci-info: | Keytype |                Fingerprint (md5)                | Options |      Comment      |
ci-info: +---------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+
ci-info: | ssh-rsa | d7:78:f4:82:71:f8:cd:4e:75:d9:ca:fd:57:f6:74:82 |    -    | Generated-by-Nova |
ci-info: +---------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+
ec2: 
ec2: #############################################################
ec2: -----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
ec2: 1024 a2:e1:7a:5d:9a:2b:83:4e:a8:07:90:6b:a2:9a:bf:19 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub (DSA)
ec2: 2048 8b:fc:3e:4a:a3:bb:3c:52:3f:a0:13:56:29:7a:d6:bb /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key.pub (RSA1)
ec2: 2048 6e:c2:99:cd:59:98:a3:d9:06:1c:ae:f9:d1:e6:56:10 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub (RSA)
ec2: -----END SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
ec2: #############################################################
-----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----
2048 35 32313190688033058191298985530558350409552981243503755532029861426754427614850471780051595180844003086009 
ssh-rsa 888WVD3T7cf/CN94GG4bLV66NIedXmdit1fpRxEOx7idyCOXsfi/53D7Lo7Ez+kqZAe4HGo0JSQ== 
-----END SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 finished at Thu, 05 Nov 2015 23:55:06 +0000. Datasource DataSourceConfigDriveNet [net,ver=2][source=/dev/sr0].  Up 17.20 seconds
Starting postfix: [  OK  ]
Starting crond: [  OK  ]

CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Kernel 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64

demo-centos login:
```

These are my config files for some important files. My instance doesn't boot with my edited "cloud.cfg" Do I need to put them in separate files?

```
[/etc/sudoers]

##
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere 
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
centos ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
## Allows members of the 'sys' group to run networking, software, 
## service management apps and more.
# %sys ALL = NETWORKING, SOFTWAR

[/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg]

system_info:
  default_user:
    name: centos
    lock_passwd: true
    gecos: Cloud User
    groups: [wheel, adm]
    sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
    shell: /bin/bash
  distro: rhel
  paths:

password: centos
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
```

Console isn't working either. Did I add the correct line for consoling?

```
[/boot/grub/menu.lst]
   grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/sda3
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
serial --unit=0 --speed=115200
terminal --timeout=10 console serial
hiddenmenu
title CentOS 6 (2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=a396de13-a505-4356-be47-14e9e600b9f9 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img
```

My instance doesn't boot with my edited "cloud.cfg" Do I need to put them in separate files? Would this enable "ssh centos@ip-address" with password of "centos" ?

Doesn't seem like my question is related to [Can't ssh into Centos vm in Openstack](https://serverfault.com/questions/650073/cant-ssh-into-centos-vm-in-openstack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStack qcow config files are very picky.
Syntax have to be in exact format. (Spacing, etc).

[/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg]

```
system_info:
  default_user:
    name: centos
    lock_passwd: true
    gecos: Cloud User
    groups: [wheel, adm]
    sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
    shell: /bin/bash
  distro: rhel
  paths:

password: centos
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
```

[/boot/grub/menu.lst - WORKED]

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/sda3
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
serial --unit=0 --speed=115200
terminal --timeout=10 console serial
hiddenmenu
title CentOS 6 (2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=a396de13-a505-4356-be47-14e9e600b9f9 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img

# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/sda2
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
serial --unit=0 --speed=115200
terminal --timeout=10 console serial
hiddenmenu
title CentOS 6 (2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=93432822-56e1-4f94-91f3-60fd80b9bfb1 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img
```

[BAM]

```
  ci-info: +-------+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway  |    Genmask    | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   0   |   10.6.1.0  | 0.0.0.0  | 255.255.255.0 |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   1   | 169.254.0.0 | 0.0.0.0  |  255.255.0.0  |    eth0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   2   |   0.0.0.0   | 10.6.1.1 |    0.0.0.0    |    eth0   |   UG  |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+----------+---------------+-----------+-------+
Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:config' at Fri, 13 Nov 2015 22:07:32 +0000. Up 27.57 seconds.
Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:final' at Fri, 13 Nov 2015 22:07:33 +0000. Up 29.43 seconds.
ci-info: ++++++++++Authorized keys from /home/centos/.ssh/authorized_keys for user centos+++++++++++
ci-info: +---------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+
ci-info: | Keytype |                Fingerprint (md5)                | Options |      Comment      |
ci-info: +---------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+
ci-info: | ssh-rsa | d7:78:f4:82:71:f8:cd:4e:75:d9:ca:fd:57:f6:74:82 |    -    | Generated-by-Nova |
ci-info: +---------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------------+
ec2: 
ec2: #############################################################
ec2: -----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
ec2: 1024 52:ef:33:97:49:d5:ac:b0:5a:59:7f:8f:80:f1:9e:d9 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub (DSA)
ec2: 2048 4d:9f:c3:05:cc:9a:3b:37:c5:0a:27:8e:08:9c:e8:61 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key.pub (RSA1)
ec2: 2048 41:e7:fd:3d:b4:26:b3:cb:6f:f8:cb:6a:31:60:92:94 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub (RSA)
ec2: -----END SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
ec2: #############################################################
-----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----
2048 35 28659583872114087976099838274719927140869079419780503337263195789109684665038761091997527137778426128641191506639125305991400855664175743627494850540768477052209487077522869031392495953447137918345409881017192368218757431758100317916696564401124818390566713036518484896494211408975565244454688550594124991034514079830180604880730593285771111372620489778017011638099267706767457481638139820921787639093793302084558052828243864932651608547548031101579125369522449801180176680832871839949766902603409803129900827570886216824503573705610909511994034019630804614616397546233173185123668523788122205977816079499308671859391 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAuRXdwPAl+Rs4MAJL1aXAgxUU0EVae74iI3m32uu27UYz9xBDmiDWlVwA2XwQkP/6MXBaAihW8ckBwsXSBaty400WifVfcam/HQ4eVHkV17U/48OFybGL5OjM03BBjvuBpidV1okLXSA4WOiEJiAGt8LQrh5925Y5unRN5HjX/RUBXLwzCg6LEStyQDjIbVf78LBdgpljwkgsef4fjYoDoLRxOeGjzT4P7eMYolNpKyQgLM+lMtBsmjAjA3hx+vLryjOjQ7qFmtAbbJBsvhUOj79xrOefcdzUGt8ctnE8C+Cf6eXStcifWRjEm1GcQjaVOcd5wJHnqP1o/+/+qqj/cw== 
-----END SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 finished at Fri, 13 Nov 2015 22:07:34 +0000. Datasource DataSourceConfigDriveNet [net,ver=2][source=/dev/sr0].  Up 29.63 seconds
Starting postfix: [  OK  ]
Starting crond: [  OK  ]

CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Kernel 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 on an x86_64
```

Comment: It is not clear where was the issue. It would be better if you give some comments

Comment: Done! Minor syntax